# @Transactional in tests does not roll back changes in database

Tags: spring, hibernate, junit, spring-test

I have a problem while run test class complexly, but not each method separately. Previously ORM was based on JDBCTemplate, I changed it to Hibernate. So when i run test class all methods make changes in database, but don't rolling them back.

[image: AssertionFailed errors after one completed test]

Test class:

```
package ua.com.foxminded.dao;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.Rollback;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import ua.com.foxminded.config.SpringDaoTestConfig;
import ua.com.foxminded.model.Course;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SpringDaoTestConfig.class)
@Transactional
@Rollback
class CourseDaoIT {

    private static final int GENERATED_COURSES_COUNT = 3;

    @Autowired
    private CourseDao courseDao;

    private Course expectedCourse;

    @Test
    void create_shouldCreateCourse() {

        assertEquals(GENERATED_COURSES_COUNT, courseDao.getAll().size());

        expectedCourse = new Course(1L, 2021);
        Course actualCourse = courseDao.create(expectedCourse);

        assertEquals(expectedCourse, actualCourse);
    }

    @Test
    void getById_shouldReturnCourse() {

        assertEquals(GENERATED_COURSES_COUNT, courseDao.getAll().size());
        Course course1 = courseDao.create(new Course(2021));
        Course course2 = courseDao.create(new Course(2022));
        Course course3 = courseDao.create(new Course(2023));

        expectedCourse = course2;
        Optional<Course> actualCourse = courseDao.getById(expectedCourse.getId());
        assertTrue(actualCourse.isPresent());
        assertEquals(expectedCourse, actualCourse.get());
    }

    @Test
    void getAll_shouldReturnAllCourses() {

        assertEquals(GENERATED_COURSES_COUNT, courseDao.getAll().size());
        Course course1 = courseDao.create(new Course(2021));
        Course course2 = courseDao.create(new Course(2022));
        Course course3 = courseDao.create(new Course(2023));

        List<Course> expectedCourses = Arrays.asList(course1, course2, course3);
        List<Course> actualCourses = courseDao.getAll().stream().skip(GENERATED_COURSES_COUNT).collect(Collectors.toList());

        assertEquals(expectedCourses, actualCourses);
    }

    @Test
    void delete_shouldDeleteCourse() {

        assertEquals(GENERATED_COURSES_COUNT, courseDao.getAll().size());
        Course course = courseDao.create(new Course(2021));
        assertEquals(GENERATED_COURSES_COUNT + 1, courseDao.getAll().size());

        courseDao.delete(course.getId());

        assertEquals(GENERATED_COURSES_COUNT, courseDao.getAll().size());
    }

    @Test
    void update_shouldUpdateCourse() {


        assertEquals(GENERATED_COURSES_COUNT, courseDao.getAll().size());
        Course course = courseDao.create(new Course(2021));
        int randomEstablishYear = course.getEstablishYear() + 285;

        assertEquals(GENERATED_COURSES_COUNT + 1, courseDao.getAll().size());

        course.setEstablishYear(randomEstablishYear);
        courseDao.update(course);

        Optional<Course> updatedCourse = courseDao.getById(course.getId());

        assertTrue(updatedCourse.isPresent());
        assertEquals(updatedCourse.get(), course);
    }
}
```

Dao class:

```
package ua.com.foxminded.dao;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver;
import ua.com.foxminded.exception.ClassNotFoundException;

import javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

/**
 * DAO class AbstractDao
 *
 * @param <T> the type of ua.com.foxminded.model package classes
 */
public abstract class AbstractDao<T> {

    /**
     * Property - logger to log important actions
     */
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AbstractDao.class.getName());

    /**
     * Property - generic type
     */
    private final Class<T> genericType;
    /**
     * Property - session factory
     */
    private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    /**
     * Property - simple class name
     */
    private final String simpleClassName;

    /**
     * Constructor autowired by SessionFactory bean.
     *
     * <p> Defines session factory, using Spring
     *
     * <p> Defines child class type, using GenericTypeResolver
     *
     * <p> Defines simple class name, using generic type for logger
     *
     * @param sessionFactory autowired SessionFactory bean
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException if class of described by AbstractDao value is not found
     * @see GenericTypeResolver#resolveTypeArgument(Class, Class)
     */
    @Autowired
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected AbstractDao(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        Class<?> classType = GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArgument(getClass(), AbstractDao.class);
        this.genericType = (Class<T>) classType;
        if (genericType == null) {
            throw new ClassNotFoundException("Generic type in AbstractDao is null");
        }
        this.simpleClassName = this.genericType.getSimpleName();
    }

    /**
     * Returns created object in table mapped by value class type
     *
     * @param value value to create
     * @return non-null value with defined id, described by AbstractDao
     */
    public T create(T value) {

        try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {

            session.beginTransaction();
            logger.debug("Creating new {} object", simpleClassName);
            value = genericType.cast(session.merge(value));
            logger.debug("{} object has been created", simpleClassName);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            return value;
        }
    }


    /**
     * If a value with param id is present in table mapped by this class type,
     * returns an Optional describing the value, otherwise throws NullPointerException
     *
     * @param id id of searching in database object
     * @return an Optional describing the value of this Optional,
     * if a value with param id is present in table mapped by this class type, and the value
     * matches the given predicate, otherwise returns null
     * @throws NullPointerException if value with param id is not present in database
     */
    public Optional<T> getById(long id) {

        try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {

            session.beginTransaction();
            logger.debug("Getting {} object by id = {}", simpleClassName, id);
            T obtainedObject = session.get(genericType, id);
            logger.debug("{} object with id ={} has been obtained", simpleClassName, id);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            return Optional.of(obtainedObject);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns a list of all values of type described this AbstractDao in mapped table of a database
     *
     * @return a list of all values of type described this AbstractDao in mapped table of a database
     */
    public List<T> getAll() {

        try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {
            session.beginTransaction();
            logger.debug("Getting all {} objects", simpleClassName);
            List<T> obtainedObjects = session.createQuery(
                "SELECT a FROM " + simpleClassName + " a", genericType).getResultList();
            logger.debug("All objects {} have been obtained", simpleClassName);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            return obtainedObjects;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Deletes object with param id from the table mapped by the class described in AbstractDao,
     * if object with such param id is present in database, otherwise throws EntityNotFoundException
     *
     * @param id id of deleting from database object
     * @throws ua.com.foxminded.exception.EntityNotFoundException if object with such param id is not present in database
     */
    public void delete(long id) {

        try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {

            session.beginTransaction();
            logger.debug("Deleting {} object with id = {}", simpleClassName, id);
            T value = session.load(genericType, id);
            session.delete(value);
            logger.debug("{} object with id = {} has been deleted", simpleClassName, id);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates object in table mapped by class type if object with id defined in param value is present,
     * otherwise throws OptimisticLockException
     *
     * @param value value to update object in database with such value's id
     * @throws OptimisticLockException if object with id defined in param value
     *                                 is not present in database
     */
    public void update(T value) {

        try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {

            session.beginTransaction();
            logger.debug("Updating {} object", simpleClassName);
            session.update(value);
            logger.debug("{} object has been updated", simpleClassName);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }
    }
}
```

I was trying to change CRUD methods in DAO. Some don't help. Others break all project. I think it has a smarter solution.

ANSWER:

Solution was in changing Repository class (AbstractDao). There were added @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED) annotation on top and changed a creating a new Session in each function to creating a field Session which calls sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(). For example: [My AbstractDao](https://github.com/HighlandProger/university/blob/hibernate/src/main/java/ua/com/foxminded/dao/AbstractDao.java)

Answer (score 0):

You're using `sessionFactory.openSession()` and manually starting and committing transactions with Hibernate.

So those transactions are not managed by Spring.

To use Spring-managed transactions with Hibernate, use Spring's `LocalSessionFactoryBean` in XML config or `LocalSessionFactoryBuilder` in Java Config.

Then, in your DAO/repository implementation use `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` to get the current Spring-managed `Session` instead of opening a new `Session`, and remove all usage of `session.beginTransaction()` and `session.getTransaction().commit()`.

You'll also need to use Spring's `HibernateTransactionManager`.

See the [Hibernate Transaction Setup](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#transaction-strategies-hibernate) and [Hibernate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#orm-hibernate) sections of the Spring Framework reference manual for details.

Comment: I will explore the material, you sent. Thank you a lot!

Comment: I changed my config class as you recomended. So it looks like [link] (https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=iooifun%2FSpring%2FSpring-master%2Fpet-sitter%2F07-ps-hibernate-practice%2Fsrc%2Ftest%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fps%2Fconfig%2FTestDataConfig.java#). All functions work in main. But i'm still having a problem with rolling back my changes in tests

Answer (score 0):

I changed my DataConfig file to this [ConfigFile](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=iooifun%2FSpring%2FSpring-master%2Fpet-sitter%2F07-ps-hibernate-practice%2Fsrc%2Ftest%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fps%2Fconfig%2FTestDataConfig.java#) and set @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED) in my **Repository** (AbstractDao)

Comment: You should edit your post and eventualy put the comment about changes instead of putting new answer.

Comment: Look please. Did i do everything right? Thanks!